# 'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to use grunt maven plugin in a maven javascript project to use grunt as a minifying tool mainly. When i build my project, i get the following BUILD FAILURE message :

```
[INFO] OS Name: Windows 7
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

Failed to execute goal pl.allegro:grunt-maven-plugin:1.5.0:grunt (default) on project
```

I m using eclipse IDE, tomcat Server. I have installed the nodejs, run the npm -g grunt cli command in cmd prompt. Please help me. If you need further details please let me know. Thankyou.